# Confusion with pygame image to string order of pixels

Tags: python, image, pygame

I'm extremely confused by a certain element of how pygame image to string works. I'm attempting to get this image as a string:

[image: this]

Now what i was expecting was a long line of one color code followed by a long line of the other color code. What i received was 2 colors of the same type, followed by another two of the other type, followed by the first 2 colors, followed by the second color code and so on until i reached the end of the image. This is incredibly confusing to me and i was wondering if someone can possibly give me some insight into this. For the program I'm working on to work essentially i need the first case (Long string of one color followed by a long string of the other) and I'm wondering the following things

1. Why does this occur? More specifically why the image code essentially a long striped string
2. Is there a way i can fix this? For example a different library or something of the like
3. If there is no other library or something simple like that. Is there a more complex way of fixing this issue

Here are some things you may need:

The output string resulting from the pygame image to string command:

> b'\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff'
>   (Would  have used pastebin, stackoverflow blocked me from using it. It has good reason but this is not code that i can clearly demonstrate)

I believe that's everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A standard method of storing image data is as a "bitmap", where each pixel is represented by 32 bits: first 8 bits red, second 8 bits green, third 8 bits blue, last 8 bits alpha (transparency).  Four bytes describe one pixel, so therefore the second pixel begins at the fifth byte and so on.   Pygame does not, unfortunately, document how the pixels are mapped to the string.  So you have to guess.

Assuming the above description is correct, you could get all the pixels of a particular color with Python slice notation.  If the list of all the pixels is named `all_pixels`, then the pixels of each color are simply:

```
red_pixels = all_pixels[0::4]
green_pixels = all_pixels[1::4]
blue_pixels = all_pixels[2::4]
```

Comment: For it to work i need to have each pixels that are the same lined up in a clear row. Is there a specific way to move these pixels around so that the pixels will be lined up in the way they are on the image, i need that out come.

Comment: I don't know what you mean, sorry.  By "a clear row" do you mean a raster row of the image?  To me, "pixels that are the same" means a list of pixels that all have exactly the same RGB color.  I can't understand "move those pixels around so that the pixels will be lined up in the way they are on the image", because they are **already** lined up, and if you move them around they will no longer be lined up the way they are on the image.

Comment: Ok, i understand i need to explain more. The way the actual image looks is a series of black pixel lined up on the top of the image and red on the bottom. Now the way I'm defining how it looks is as (assume black was 6 and red was 5) [6,6,6,6,6,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]. However the actual way its being lined up is essentially as [6,5,6,5,6,5,6,5,6,5,6,5]. (Obviously not 100% true just bare with me) what i wan't to do is to re-arange the numbers so they are in the way I'm defining as how it looks. Essentially in this case long lines of the same color

Comment: Each pixel isn't a number; it's a sequence of four bytes RGBA.  Thus a red pixel is represented by four characters, `\xff\x00\x00\xff`.  A black pixel is `\x00\x00\x00\xff`.  If you look at the string you provided, it consists of a lot of red pixels followed by a lot of black ones.  If your description of the image is correct, the data starts at the **bottom** of the image, not the **top**, but otherwise looks like what you want: [red, red, red, ... black, black, black].  image.tostring has a keyword `flipped` which changes whether the string starts at the bottom or the top.

Comment: What you just told me made the compressor I'm working on about ten times better, thank you. This is probably the most I've ever learned doing a project in python, thank you. This probably sufficiently answers my question

Comment: Can you give me a link to all image codes like this?

Comment: Please accept the answer if you found it helpful.  The image format used here is typical of how RGB (red-green-blue) images are represented on a computer (or TV or digital camera).  This wikipedia article will tell you more than you ever wanted to know: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model.